# binding to a combobox getting different results when using using SelectedValue

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, combobox

I have bound to my combobox this simple class:

```
  public class Company
  {
    public Guid CorporationId { set; get; }
    public Guid TokenId { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
  }
```

And this is my binding:

```
private void FillCompaniesComboBox()
{
  _doneLoadingComboBox = false;
  comboBox_Companies.Items.Clear();

  if (CurrentSettings.AllCompanies.Count == 0)
  {
    return;
  }

  bindingSource1.DataSource = CurrentSettings.AllCompanies;
  comboBox_Companies.DataSource = bindingSource1.DataSource;
  comboBox_Companies.DisplayMember = "Name";
  comboBox_Companies.ValueMember = "CorporationId";
  comboBox_Companies.SelectedIndex = 1;
  _doneLoadingComboBox = true;
}
```

When I attempt to get the value of the selected item, I'm getting different results. Here is the code I am using to get my value:

```
private void comboBox_Companies_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!_doneLoadingComboBox && comboBox_Companies.SelectedIndex == -1)
  {
    return;
  }

  var value = (Company)comboBox_Companies.SelectedValue;

  Console.WriteLine("Value: " + value.CorporationId);

}
```

Here is what is happening:

This one works at intended:

[image]

And this is were it is causing an issue:

[image]

Am I not retrieving the data correctly? I need the Company information that it is bound to.

Comment: `SelectedValue` will return `CorporationId` because you set its as the `ValueMember`, been a while since I've used winforms but I think there is also a `SeletedItem` property which should return the entire object.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 This was exactly what I needed. I used SelectedItem and it worked. If you will give this as an answer I will upvote you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so here's what you need to do...

Assuming that your `CurrentSettings.AllCompanies` is an `IList<Company>` that you've already populated with data, here's what your code should look like:

```
public class ComboBoxItem {
    // your class
    private Company Comp;
}

private readonly BindingSource _bsSelectedCompany = new BindingSource();
private readonly ComboBoxItem _comboBoxItem = new ComboBoxItem();

// your main form method
public MainForm() {

    // initialization code...
    InitializeComponent();

    // prevents errors in case your data binding objects are empty
    ResetComboBox(comboBox1);

    comboBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding(
        "SelectedItem",
        _bsSelectedCompany,
        "Comp",
        false,
        DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged
    ));

    comboBox1.DataSource = CurrentSettings.AllCompanies;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
}

// simple method for resetting a given combo box to a default state
private static void ResetComboBox(ComboBox comboBox) {
    comboBox.Items.Clear();
    comboBox.Items.Add("Select a method...");
    comboBox.SelectedItem = comboBox.Items[0];
}
```

By doing this, you're able to just use `_comboBoxItem` to safely get the information about your selected item without having to potentially `Invoke` it (in the case of accessing it on a separate thread).